# Flutter: How to change the color in the background (or overlay color) of an Icon when it's pressed?

Tags: flutter, iconbutton

Here my code:

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add_circled),
          color: Colors.orange,
          iconSize: CustomTheme.iconSize,
          splashColor: Colors.pink,
        
          onPressed: () {
           .....anything
          },
        ),
```

When I press the IconButton on the left side, it gets a grey circled background which will be filled by the pink splash color.

My question: How can I change the GREY color or even remove it completely???

[image: Unpressed Icon]  --->  When  Icon is pressed ---->  [image: Pressed Icon]

Comment: try to use setState method on your onpress button

Answer (score 0):

add the following property

```
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 2 properties to Colors.transparent

```
IconButton(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
```